# Finding where values come to the $model

Tags: yii2

I changed the login page layout and got error that `$model` is undefined variable in Yii.

How can I find where values come to the `$model`?

Where is the `model` variable declared?

Error page:

[image: error page]

Comment: Check the controller that renders the view, the render/renderPartial methods receive an array with all the view variables passed to it, if you're not defining the model there, then you can't access it within your view

Comment: Update your question adding your related layout code .. and controller/action code .. please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the controllers directory you can find the `SiteController.php` controller file. In this controller class you can find the below index method. For example

```
public function actionIndex() {
  $model = new YourModelClassName(); //your model file class name replace here
  return $this->render('index', ['model' => $model]);
}
```